# Compactness of set of Lipschitz functions $f:D\rightarrow D$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, compactness, lipschitz-functions

Denote by $D:=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^2\text{ such that } ||z||\le 1\}$ the unitary closed disk: it is a metric space with the induced Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Fix any $k>0$ and denote by $Lip_k(D)$ the set of continuous functions $f:D\rightarrow D$ with Lipschitz constant $k$.

On $Lip_k(D)$ consider any of the following topologies:

- the compact open topology
- the topology of pointwise convergence
- the $L^\infty$-topology

**Question 1:** Is $Lip_k(D)$ compact with respect to any of the previous topologies? Can you motivate your answer or point me our a reference?

I am sorry if I can not show my attempt, but I do not really know how to prove that, given any sequence $\{f_n\}\subset Lip_k(D)$, there must always be a converging subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ with limit $f\in Lip_k(D)$.

**Question 2:** If $Lip_k(D)$ is not compact, then will it change if we consider $Lip_k^0(D)$, the set of $k$-Lipschitz functions which coincide with the identity on $\partial D$?

Comment: Note constants are in $\text {Lip}_k,$ so it doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Since the functions are continuous on the *compact* $D$, the compact open topology and the $L^\infty$-topology coincide.

Comment: @zhw thank you, then will it be true with some additional conditions as the one I added?

Comment: What you need is boundedness. A subset of $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ is relatively compact if and only if it is pointwise bounded (which in this situation is equivalent to being uniformly bounded, and also equivalent to being bounded at one point of $D$). For compactness you also need the set to be closed. This is the case for $\operatorname{Lip}_k^0(D)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for your comment. I can not understand the condition of being bounded at one point of $D$: since we consider functions $f:D\rightarrow D$ isn't it obvious that there exists an $M>0$ such that for every $x\in D$ and $f\in Lip_k(D)$ it results $|f(x)|\le M$ and in particular $M=1$? Why should one add the condition of being bounded at one point?

Comment: I wasn't paying full attention and thought of functions $D \to \mathbb{R}^2$. For functions $D \to D$ the boundedness condition [which for more general codomains should be replaced with the relative compactness of the images of each point] is trivially satisfied, so already $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ is compact (and $\operatorname{Lip}_k^0(D)$ too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets deal with the case of the $L^\infty$-topology. Here it is natural to think of $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ as a subspace of $C(D)$, the space of continuous functions on $D$ equipped with the supremum norm.

We will use the [Arzela-Ascoli Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) which tells us that $F \subset C(D)$ is relatively compact if and only if it is a bounded set in the sup norm and it is equicontinuous. It is easy to see that $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ is equicontinuous and since $f \in \operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ implies $f(D) \subset D$, $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ is bounded in the supremum norm with bound $1$. Hence $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ is relatively compact.

It's an easy exercise to see that $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ is closed in $C(D)$ for the supremum norm and hence is compact.

Similarly $\operatorname{Lip}_k^0(D)$ is a bounded, equicontinuous and closed subset of $C(D)$ and so is compact.

Now $D$ is compact, so the compact open topology coincides with the $L^\infty$-topology. So we are only left to consider the topology of pointwise convergence.

This is straightforward since the $L^\infty$-topology is strictly finer than the topology of pointwise convergence and hence any compact subset of $\operatorname{Lip}_k(D)$ (or even of $C(D)$) for the $L^\infty$-topology is also compact in the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One question: you say that the fact $Lip_k^0(D)$ is uniformly bounded is implied by the fact that functions of $Lip_k^0(D)$ coincide with the identity on $\partial D$. But I do not understand the inequality $|f(x)|\le 2k+1$: since $f(x)\in D$ for every $x\in D$ and $f\in Lip_k^0(D)$, why couldn't one simply conclude $|f(x)|\le 1$ (without using the hypothesis $f|_{\partial D}=Id$)?

Comment: Good question. Somehow when writing this I managed to revert to thinking about functions from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I'll be editing it to fix this now.

Comment: @User29983 hopefully the answer should me more useful now. Sorry for the mistake!